# Can't assign string to Variant variable in Delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to assign a `UnicodeString` (or `Widestring`, tried both) value to a class field variable declared as a `Variant` in a property setter. I'm getting an error:

```
EVariantBadVarTypeError - 'Invalid variant type'
```

In the `interface` `uses` clause I have included `System.Variants`.

Here's my declaration of the `Variant` field variable:

```
TContainerClass = class(TObject)
strict private
...
type
  ...
  TInnerClass = class
  strict private
    ...
    FValue: Variant;
    function GetAsString: UnicodeString;
    ...
    procedure SetAsString(const Value: UnicodeString);
  public
    ...
    property AsString: UnicodeString read GetAsString write SetAsString;
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

In the `implementation` section here is my property setter:

```
procedure TContainerClass.TInnerClass.SetAsString(const AValue: UnicodeString);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
end;
```

Here is an example of using the property:

```
// Items is a TObjectList descendant
// each item in items is an instance of TInnerClass
TInnerClass(Items[Index]).AsString := StringList[Index]; 
// at runtime value is for ex. 'Dr.' - this assignment raises the above referenced exception
```

In stepping through the code, all objects are instantiated. Both sides of the assignment appear to be valid. The only thing that I noticed when stepping through is that when I evaluate the `TInnerClass(Items[Index])` I see this:

```
(Unknown type: 39852, (nil,$3A83700), Variant array of Unknown, $1, $F, '')
```

Probably something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid object instance?

Answer (score 1):

> (Unknown type: 39852, (nil,$3A83700), Variant array of Unknown, $1, $F, '')

It looks like something in your program has corrupted the variant object. Once you can identify that and avoid the corruption, you code should start to work.

Look for code that performs raw memory access, for instance calls to `Move` are a common source of corruptions. Likewise using stale pointers or references.

Comment: Not using Move here, so more likely a stale reference. Trying to track it down...